# Why do i get 403 error allow/deny nginx for all ips

Tags: html, http, nginx, http-status-code-404, port

Ah I faced this issue today and was able to solve it from multiple places;
For anyone facing similar issue i thought ill try to help you out

the 403 error occurs because most probably your server is not listening to the request directly from the client, ie either a loadbalancer or proxy gives the request to nginx.

to solve this use

```
set_real_ip_from 34.117.182.58/0;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

under http block (note http not server)
ie

```
http {
    set_real_ip_from 34.117.182.58/0; \n
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
}
```

this should solve the 403 error but most likely you will recieve 404 error
this is due to how nginx works to solve this add proxy_pass http://backend_server; to the location

eg:

```
location /admin {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://backend_server;
}
```

This should solve your issue :)
Hope I could be of help